# VS2015 — Link CRL with C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, clr

I'm a C# programmer and I'm trying this to make a C++/CLI wrapper. I've got three projects inside the solution:

- C++ DLL
- C++ CLR
- WPF C#

I'm just doing tests, so I got these implementations:

C++ DLL Testing.h:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

    int Increment();

private:
    int counter = 5;
};`
```

---

C++ DLL Testing.cpp

```
#include "Testing.h"

int Test::Increment()
{
    return counter++;
}
```

---

CLR Wrapper.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Testing.h"

using namespace System;

namespace Wrapper
{
    public ref class Wraptest
    {
    public:
        Wraptest();
        int Increment();

    private:
        Test* t;
    };
}
```

---

CLR Wrapper.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "PITest.h"

Wrapper::Wraptest::Wraptest()
{
    t = new Test();
}

int Wrapper::Wraptest::Increment()
{
    return t->Increment();
}
```

---

I've added a reference to the Testing C++ DLL project inside the Wrapper project. I've also added the DLL solution header files to the Additional Includes of the Wrapper.

The C++ DLL project builds well, but when I build the Wrapper project I get these errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A000007) "public: __thiscall Test::Test(void)" (??0Test@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall Wrapper::Wraptest::Wraptest(void)" (??0Wraptest@Wrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)  Wrapper C:\Users\mytoy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CodeTest\Wrapper\Wrapper.obj   1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Test::Test(void)" (??0Test@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall Wrapper::Wraptest::Wraptest(void)" (??0Wraptest@Wrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)   Wrapper C:\Users\mytoy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CodeTest\Wrapper\Wrapper.obj   1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  Wrapper C:\Users\mytoy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CodeTest\Debug\Wrapper.dll 1

---

I can't figure out the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Haven't you got to add **Testing.lib** to the Linker **Imports** section on the project properties for the _Wrapper_ project?

Comment: Looks like the problem is mis-matched  calling conventions. You might get some clues from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke) Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke.

Comment: It is a straight-forward linker error, but rather odd that it doesn't complain about Test::Increment().  It is not obvious at all what you did to ensure that the class is exported from the native DLL.  An incomplete .def file is the only reasonable guess.  You'll have to do the dllexport/dllimport attribute dance on the class declaration to ensure the entire class is exported, not just Increment().  Or build the native code as a static library instead of a DLL, that's easier.

Comment: I tried adding the "__declspec(dllexport)" attribute to the Testing class, and I get the same errors. Also I tried adding the C++ DLL folder to the Linker Input Additional Dependencies of the Wrapper. And got only this error instead -->Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\mytoy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CodeTest\Testingt\\.obj' Wrapper C:\Users\mytoy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CodeTest\Wrapper\LINK 1<--

Comment: I can try building it as a static library but I honestly wold like this to be a DLL, and I can't figure out why it's not working

Comment: UPDATE: Building the DLL as a static library works out of the box, but I actually need a DLL :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to get it working. It's prety easy.

I checked [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) and I was missing this:

```
// C++ DLL Header
#ifdef TESTING_EXPORTS  
    #define TESTING_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
    #define TESTING_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif
```

On the wrapper I just added the header location to the Additional Included Directories (Linker unchanged) and I just works out of the box.